# Azure Devops Android Release to Google Play Store fails

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm new to CI/CD. I dont understand what I'm doing wrong.
I have set up a pipeline in Azure Devops that signs aab-file and drops it in Artifacts. So far so good.

I've then created a Release that Downloads the signed AAB-file togather with JSON file of a Google's Service Account. Same here, so far so good.

Then I add task, "Push to Google Play Store". I then get this following error.

Iäm thinking that it has to do something with the warning:

> 2023-12-14T14:44:34.1599677Z ##[warning]Task 'publishPlaystore' (1.0.1) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib

**ErrorLog:** [full error log](https://mclo.gs/f25FHJH)

```html
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1317187Z ##[section]Starting: Publish to Google Play Store
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1438642Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1438793Z Task         : Publish to Google Play Store
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1438873Z Description  : Publish your APK to Google Play Store (Alpha, Beta, Production or Rollout)
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1439034Z Version      : 1.0.1
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1439096Z Author       : Alexandre Chohfi
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1439746Z Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/azchohfi/vsts-task-publish-playstore)
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1439876Z ==============================================================================
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1599677Z ##[warning]Task 'publishPlaystore' (1.0.1) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib
2023-12-14T14:44:34.1610729Z Preparing task execution handler.
2023-12-14T14:45:11.8772243Z Executing the powershell script: D:\a\_tasks\publishPlaystore_20810fda-9c24-482a-a00c-6fcc16b30fd0\1.0.1\publish.ps1
2023-12-14T14:45:12.1694094Z com.aploria.ploid
2023-12-14T14:45:12.1695899Z D:\a\r1\a\com.aploria.ploid-Signed.aab
2023-12-14T14:45:12.8169867Z Python 3.9.13
2023-12-14T14:45:12.8182799Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\python.exe
2023-12-14T14:45:12.8183362Z C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\scripts\pip.exe
2023-12-14T14:45:25.2785868Z Collecting pip
2023-12-14T14:45:25.3666993Z   Downloading pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:25.4798991Z Collecting wheel
2023-12-14T14:45:25.4958954Z   Downloading wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:25.5329374Z Downloading pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
2023-12-14T14:45:25.6441760Z    ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 19.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:25.6588550Z Downloading wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:25.6806283Z    ---------------------------------------- 65.4/65.4 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:26.2530251Z Installing collected packages: wheel, pip
2023-12-14T14:45:26.4418669Z   Attempting uninstall: pip
2023-12-14T14:45:26.4430446Z     Found existing installation: pip 23.3.1
2023-12-14T14:45:31.8234721Z     Uninstalling pip-23.3.1:
2023-12-14T14:45:31.8538138Z       Successfully uninstalled pip-23.3.1
2023-12-14T14:45:35.6094011Z Successfully installed pip-23.3.1 wheel-0.42.0
2023-12-14T14:45:37.7967959Z Collecting google-api-python-client
2023-12-14T14:45:37.8503785Z   Downloading google_api_python_client-2.111.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:37.9207987Z Collecting httplib2<1.dev0,>=0.15.0 (from google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:37.9383627Z   Downloading httplib2-0.22.0-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:37.9700067Z      ---------------------------------------- 96.9/96.9 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:38.1190681Z Collecting google-auth<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.19.0 (from google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.1342017Z   Downloading google_auth-2.25.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.1803934Z Collecting google-auth-httplib2>=0.1.0 (from google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.2136515Z   Downloading google_auth_httplib2-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.3606823Z Collecting google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5 (from google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.3757858Z   Downloading google_api_core-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.4291030Z Collecting uritemplate<5,>=3.0.1 (from google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.4479235Z   Downloading uritemplate-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.5267997Z Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0.dev0,>=1.56.2 (from google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.5418194Z   Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.62.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.8648820Z Collecting protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5 (from google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:38.8820064Z   Downloading protobuf-4.25.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (541 bytes)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.0171399Z Collecting requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0 (from google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.0384298Z   Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.1156905Z Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.19.0->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.1308224Z   Downloading cachetools-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.1998540Z Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.19.0->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.2153822Z   Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.2473342Z      ------------------------------------- 181.3/181.3 kB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:39.2979924Z Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4 (from google-auth<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.19.0->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.3134946Z   Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.4200581Z Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.3,<4,>=2.4.2 (from httplib2<1.dev0,>=0.15.0->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.4362202Z   Downloading pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.5395953Z Collecting pyasn1<0.6.0,>=0.4.6 (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.19.0->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.5648851Z   Downloading pyasn1-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.7406512Z Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.7561907Z   Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.8165369Z Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.8323319Z   Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.9320274Z Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:39.9472379Z   Downloading urllib3-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.0136347Z Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0.dev0,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.0285081Z   Downloading certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.1214665Z Downloading google_api_python_client-2.111.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13.0 MB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.3369582Z    ---------------------------------------- 13.0/13.0 MB 59.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.3523333Z Downloading google_api_core-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.3732700Z    ---------------------------------------- 122.0/122.0 kB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.3930437Z Downloading google_auth-2.25.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (184 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.4130176Z    --------------------------------------- 184.2/184.2 kB 11.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.4279385Z Downloading google_auth_httplib2-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.4601263Z Downloading cachetools-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.4896239Z Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.62.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (228 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.5131188Z    --------------------------------------- 228.7/228.7 kB 14.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.5284945Z Downloading protobuf-4.25.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (413 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.5528725Z    --------------------------------------- 413.4/413.4 kB 25.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.5680952Z Downloading pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.5961269Z    ---------------------------------------- 103.1/103.1 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.6111335Z Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.6295109Z    ---------------------------------------- 62.6/62.6 kB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.6450127Z Downloading certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.6692810Z    --------------------------------------- 162.5/162.5 kB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.6846376Z Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (100 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7049681Z    ---------------------------------------- 100.4/100.4 kB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7204933Z Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7394150Z    ---------------------------------------- 61.6/61.6 kB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7539512Z Downloading pyasn1-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7735391Z    ---------------------------------------- 84.9/84.9 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:40.7889093Z Downloading urllib3-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
2023-12-14T14:45:40.8075106Z    ---------------------------------------- 104.6/104.6 kB 5.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2023-12-14T14:45:41.2280459Z Installing collected packages: urllib3, uritemplate, pyparsing, pyasn1, protobuf, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, cachetools, rsa, requests, pyasn1-modules, httplib2, googleapis-common-protos, google-auth, google-auth-httplib2, google-api-core, google-api-python-client
2023-12-14T14:45:46.1600853Z Successfully installed cachetools-5.3.2 certifi-2023.11.17 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 google-api-core-2.15.0 google-api-python-client-2.111.0 google-auth-2.25.2 google-auth-httplib2-0.2.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.62.0 httplib2-0.22.0 idna-3.6 protobuf-4.25.1 pyasn1-0.5.1 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 pyparsing-3.1.1 requests-2.31.0 rsa-4.9 uritemplate-4.1.1 urllib3-2.1.0
2023-12-14T14:45:47.6629727Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-14T14:45:47.6632013Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException:   File "D:\a\_tasks\publishPlaystore_20810fda-9c24-482a-a00c-6fcc16b30fd0\1.0.1\upload_apks_with_listing.py", line 27, in <module>
2023-12-14T14:45:47.6633959Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException:     from oauth2client import tools
2023-12-14T14:45:47.6635368Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'
2023-12-14T14:45:47.7080113Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 4 errors.
2023-12-14T14:45:47.7087675Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish to Google Play Store
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [guide](https://github.com/azchohfi/vsts-task-publish-playstore), the "Push to Google Play Store" extension is NOT maintained, please use Microsoft Official extension [Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) for the publish.

[image]

In order to automate the release of app updates to the Google Play store, you need to have manually released at least one version through the [Google Play Developer Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en).

Then in DevOps pipeline, you can add `Google Play - Release` task to deploy app bundle(.aab), use `JSON auth` for Authentication method, and choose the aab file.

[image]

[image]

Please refer to links below for the details:

[Publish to Google Play Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/googleplay)

[google-play---release](https://github.com/Microsoft/google-play-vsts-extension#google-play---release-bundle)